# How to get the correct position of recyclerView after search filter has been applied

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I've implemented a `recyclerView` which populates `JSON` data from `REST` method. I've also added a `searchView` on the toolbar that filters the `recyclerview` according the data entered in the `searchview`. Now i'm facing a problem where on clicking on an item in the `recyclerview` after entering the search parameters it always returns the first element in the list that was populated from the rest method.

**Adapter.java**

```
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<RetailerOfferPOJO> data;
private static ClickListener clickListener;

public RetailerOfferAdapter(Context context, List<RetailerOfferPOJO> data) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.retailer_offer_adapter, parent, false);
    MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder)holder;
    RetailerOfferPOJO current = data.get(position);
    //myHolder.lblID.setText(current.getsID());
    myHolder.lblOfferName.setText(current.getsOfferName());
    myHolder.lblDescription.setText(current.getsDescription());
    myHolder.lblPrice.setText(current.getsPrice());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

/**
 * Search Filter method for RecyclerView
 * @param searchModels
 */
public void setFilter(List<RetailerOfferPOJO> searchModels) {
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.addAll(searchModels);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{

    TextView lblID;
    TextView lblOfferName;
    TextView lblDescription;
    TextView lblPrice;

    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        // lblID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblID);
        lblOfferName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblOfferName);
        lblDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblDescription);
        lblPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblPrice);

    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            final List<RetailerOfferPOJO> filteredModelList = filter(mRetailerOffers, newText);
            if (!filteredModelList.isEmpty()) {
                mAdapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
            }

            return true;
        }

    });




/**
 * Filter method for RecyclerView
 *
 * @param models
 * @param query -> data entered by the user as search parameter
 * @return
 */
private List<RetailerOfferPOJO> filter(List<RetailerOfferPOJO> models, String query) {

    //@param query -> the data entered by user is taken and converted to lowe case
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<RetailerOfferPOJO> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (RetailerOfferPOJO model : models) {
        // the data that is populated in the RecyclerView is converted to lower case
        //full name and designation is attached to model class so that when the user searches
        //on either of them the recycler view displays data accordingly
        final String text = model.getsOfferName().toLowerCase();
        final String text1 = model.getsDescription().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            //check if the text in the recycler view contains the data entered by the user
            // and then update the list
            filteredModelList.add(model);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if (text1.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }

    }
   // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return filteredModelList;
}
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) generic adapter, call `getFilter()` method for filtering

Comment: it may be because, your click listener still uses the old list and not the new "filteredModelList"

Comment: Thank you Harjot SIngh Oberai for the tip. It is working now. the mistake that i did was i reinitialized the my model class in the search filter as a result the recyclerview clicklistener event was done in the old list.                    Thank you pskink for your response but i did not try out you way. Will give it a try